# Does Expanded Arsenal (Magic School) sum up all available focuses?

Tags: pathfinder-wrath-of-the-righteous

The Mythic feat "Expanded Arsenal (Magic School)" is described as:

> Select one school of magic. All bonuses from your feats and mythic feats that apply to another school of magic, such as Spell Focus feat and School Specialization mythic feat, now apply to the chosen school of magic too.

I am a bit unsure how to understand that: It is clear that if I have Spell Focus - Illusion and Greater Spell Focus - Illusion (giving together +2 bonus points) and I get mythic Expanded Arsenal - Evocation, that +2 bonus from the Illusion School will be now also applying to Evocation. But what if I have Spell focus in multiple schools? Will that be summed up?

Let's say that I have Spell Focus in Illusion, Abjuration and Conjuring - each gives +1 difficulty bonus to the specific school. If I'd take EA: Evocation, will my bonus to Evocation will be +1 (because that was the highest bonus from all other Spell Focus feats) or +3 (because I'll be summing up 3 x +1 bonuses)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be so. I'm not sure is it a bug or a feature but indeed that how it works:

I have Spell Focus: Illusion, which gives me +1 to the difficulty level of all casted illusion spells - to a total level 30.

I have also 3 other SF and 1 Greater SF. With an Expanded Arsenal (Evocation), my casts from that level have difficulty level 35.